# Best practices for testing a netTcp WCF service at development environment

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-express

I have got a `netTcp` WCF service. This service will be hosted at IIS 7.5 at production time.

But is it necessary to install IIS 7.5 also at the development machine to debug the service?
I'm not able to use the built-in `Cassini` server or `IIS Express`, because both do not support `netTcp`. I don't have a good feeling when installing a full web server just for debugging, so I want to know if there are any other possibilities.

How do you debug `netTcp` WCF services?
Of course there are several options:

- Install IIS 7.5
- Self-host the WCF app and port it to IIS 7.5 later
- Something like [WcfSvcHost.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552363.aspx)
- ...

> Note to WcfSvcHost.exe: *I can't find such tool in **Visual Web
>   Developer Express 2010**. Is it still possible to use this tool in
>   Visual Web Developer Express 2010?
>   If the option WcfSvcHost.exe is suggested, it would be nice to hear a solution for this  problem.*

What are the advantages/disadvantages of each option in following aspects?

- How close to reality?
- Installation effort
- Security (Is installing a full web server a good idea?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I do WCF development, I always separate my service from the hosting implementation. This gives you a greater level of flexibility if your hosting decision changes in the future (for instance, IIS wasn't a very good choice of hosting platform when WCF first came out for various reasons, but now it's pretty much the preferred method). I typically have a DebugHost console app as one of the projects in my solution, where I self-host my services during development. All that project does is host whatever service I happen to be debugging; the actual service itself is located in its own Class Library project, and it's not dependent on how it ends up being hosted, whether in development or production.

Of course this means your development environment won't exactly match production, so I would recommend having some type of staging environment before you actually go live to verify that your configuration works with IIS before you go into production.

Comment: Thanks! Many things were solved with your answer and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/wcfbyexample_baseline.aspx.